# Clarification for rejected edit

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering why [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5699105) was rejected. It seems like a pretty cut-and-dry correction of a semantic error. The question says the compiler and I get this error when compiling the original code with the `-std=c99` flag:

`test.c:11:12: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Where line 11 is :

`return i < SIZE-1;`

Comment: It looks like the OP of that answer rejected it. That's binding. He might have disagreed with what you said. At the same time, after your edit, he did edit his own answer.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware that answerers could reject edits out-of-hand.

Comment: Yeah, the OP of any post can single-handedly reject or accept edits, depending on if they agree with them or not. The answers you've received give excellent advice on what to do in these situations.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to do edits in code, as certain code decisions might not be immediately clear to you, but were made consciously by the author. It is often better to leave a quick comment saying "hey, this did not work with `-std=c99`, you probably should move the variable `i` out of the for-loop."

Comment: It's also too minor.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I don't usually edit other people's code, however this is a blatant bug and his code doesn't compile. In this case it's very clear what the intent is. In the future I'll just downvote and comment, since that seems to be the "in model" method for getting that message across.

Comment: @staticx In the grand scheme of the answer you are correct, however, in general, I wholly disagree that compiler errors are "minor" things!

Comment: @maxywb: we don't want minor edits..they need to be substantial. Add a comment to the OPs answer and move on. Up to them to make the minor mod

Comment: @staticx if you'll refer to my first comment, I point out that this wasn't clear to me. I must have missed that in the "best practices" guide.

Comment: @maxywb: No need to be sarcastic. If you truly want to learn, then you ask and read.

Comment: Looking at it again, it looks like the OP did make an edit similar to your suggested change- And more in the same edit. It could be that he didn't see your edit and was making his change, and yours got rejected when he submitted his edit. Or he saw your edit, realized you were going in the right direction, but your edit was off.

Comment: I'd say it was the later of the situations I suggested: Your edit seems to have taken the first `i` out of the for loop completely, which I believe would break the code still.

Comment: @staticx I can't help myself. Sarcasm is, obviously imo, an important method of emphasis in purely textual communication.

Comment: @Kendra C++ has lexical scoping rules, so the `i` is visible in each "child" scope of where it is defined. If you'll note the answerers' change does the exact same thing, just moving the declaration to the top of the function. His aversion to my changes is probably that he wanted to declare explicitly `int32_t` and group it with the other declaration.

Comment: @maxywb To quote his edit: `for (i = 0; arrayPtr[i] != compareVal; i++);` The `i` is still there. Your edit had it removed. I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying that could be why he rejected it first. The edit I speak of [still has the `i` and the int was change in the next edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25662703/9)

Comment: @maxywb Actually, now you've confused me. What does C++ have to do with a question tagged as C?

Comment: @Kendra I guess I misspoke, either way c/c++ have the same scoping rules so what I said still applies.

Comment: @maxywb Fair enough. Either way, you did get your answer. I was just attempting to give a little insight. Thanks for responding- I learned something through it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author of the post felt that your edit was incorrect.  He of course has every right to provide the solution that he feels is correct.  If you feel that his solution is incorrect you can indicate that feedback to others by downvoting and/or commenting on the post.  You could also post a competing answer (citing the other if appropriate) if you wanted to.

Edits are there to improve the presentation of the existing content.  While you can fix errors, they should be errors in which the author of the post clearly *meant* to do what you are editing the post to, rather than changing the post from what the author intended to something different.  While personally I would likely consider this edit to be appropriate, were I evaluating it, as it *does* seem to be the author's intent, the fact that the author rejected the edit removes all possible doubt in the matter.  Clearly they want the code to do what it's doing.  If that's wrong then the post is simply wrong, and that's that.

Answer (score 4):

One of the people who rejected was the author of that post so he can reject the edit unilateraly.

That person obviously disagrees with you.

If you are concerned about it then you could leave a comment on your post. If you do this, just be sure to comment in a way that isn't condescending, rude, or otherwise offensive.